# Array returned from function modified by printing newline

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to write a simple `linspace` function in C similar to Numpy's `np.linspace`, but am getting strange behaviour I don't understand.

The `linspace` function takes in a starting number, a stopping number, and the number of elements in the array. E.g.`linspace(0,5,5)`
produces an array that looks like `[0., 1.25, 2.5, 3.75, 5.]`

My code is below.  `linspace` is defined, and then `main`.  `main` goes through examples of things that puzzle me.

#### Code

```
    double *linspace(double start, double stop, int num) {
        double a[num];
        double spacing = (stop-start)/(num-1);
        int i;
        printf("Output of function linspace:\n");
        for (i=0; i<num; i++){
            a[i] = start + i*spacing;
            printf("a[%d] = %f, &a[%d] = %p\n", i, a[i], i, &a[i]);
        }
        return a;
    }

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

        int N = 5;
        double start = 1;
        double stop = 5;
        int i;

        /* Testing linspace */
        double *a = linspace(start, stop, N);
    //     double a[N];
    //     a[0] = 1; a[1]=2; a[2]=3; a[3]=4; a[4]=5;

        printf("Printing a line with no \\n does nothing to the array...");
        for (i=0; i<N; i++){
            printf("a[%d] = %f, &a[%d] = %p\n", i, a[i], i, &a[i]);
        }

        printf("Printing a line with \\n resets some of the array elements...\n");
        for (i=0; i<N; i++){
            printf("a[%d] = %f, &a[%d] = %p\n", i, a[i], i, &a[i]);
        }

        printf("Defining double y[N] prior to the loop modifies array a again:");
        double y[N];
        for (i=0; i<N; i++){
            printf("a[%d] = %f, &a[%d] = %p\n", i, a[i], i, &a[i]);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

#### Code Output

The printed output looks like this, which I am puzzled by because printing `\n` and defining new variables seems to be setting values of array `a` to 0.

```
    Output of function linspace:
    a[0] = 1.000000, &a[0] = 0xbfe7d968
    a[1] = 2.000000, &a[1] = 0xbfe7d970
    a[2] = 3.000000, &a[2] = 0xbfe7d978
    a[3] = 4.000000, &a[3] = 0xbfe7d980
    a[4] = 5.000000, &a[4] = 0xbfe7d988
    Printing a line with no \n does nothing to the array...a[0] = 1.000000, &a[0] = 0xbfe7d968
    a[1] = 2.000000, &a[1] = 0xbfe7d970
    a[2] = 3.000000, &a[2] = 0xbfe7d978
    a[3] = 4.000000, &a[3] = 0xbfe7d980
    a[4] = 5.000000, &a[4] = 0xbfe7d988
    Printing a line with \n resets some of the array elements...
    a[0] = -0.000000, &a[0] = 0xbfe7d968
    a[1] = -0.000000, &a[1] = 0xbfe7d970
    a[2] = 3.000000, &a[2] = 0xbfe7d978
    a[3] = 4.000000, &a[3] = 0xbfe7d980
    a[4] = -0.000000, &a[4] = 0xbfe7d988
    Defining double y[N] prior to the loop modifies array a again:a[0] = -0.000000, &a[0] = 0xbfe7d968
    a[1] = -0.000000, &a[1] = 0xbfe7d970
    a[2] = 0.000000, &a[2] = 0xbfe7d978
    a[3] = 4.000000, &a[3] = 0xbfe7d980
    a[4] = -0.000000, &a[4] = 0xbfe7d988
```

(`y[N]` above uses a different memory address than `a`, I checked.)

If, instead of getting an array from a function: `double *a = linspace(start, stop, N);`, I manually defined an array (the lines that are commented out in the code):

```
    double a[N];
    a[0] = 1; a[1]=2; a[2]=3; a[3]=4; a[4]=5;
```

then every single print command prints similar output to this, which I expected:

```
    a[0] = 1.000000, &a[0] = 0xbf85f8a8
    a[1] = 2.000000, &a[1] = 0xbf85f8b0
    a[2] = 3.000000, &a[2] = 0xbf85f8b8
    a[3] = 4.000000, &a[3] = 0xbf85f8c0
    a[4] = 5.000000, &a[4] = 0xbf85f8c8
```

If it's a problem with the way I am using arrays, could you please explain why doing something (e.g. printing `\n` and defining variables) after an array is returned from the function can change elements in the array, and show how you might fix it? Thanks in advance!

My background has mainly been in Python.

Comment: Your error is reflected in the title of your question: `Array returned from function...`. You should not return a local array from a function!

Comment: `double *linspace(double start, double stop, int num) { double a[num]; ...     return a;  }` returns the address of a local variable that is now out of scope.  Reccomend passing in array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a pointer on an array allocated on the stack.

`double a[num];` allocates the array on the stack. When you return a, you return a pointer to an array that is disposed when the function returns. So the pointer address points inside the stack as maybe overwritten later.